# Why does std::sort assume a std::vector< std::vector<int> > to be a std::vector by default, thereby creating wrong results?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector, stl

I have created a vector of vectors and I would like to sort them based on parameters that I define. Here, the `sort()` function takes the variable dataset defined as `vector<vector<int>>` to be just a `vector<int>`. Could someone explain what is going wrong?

Moreover, even after the above said problem is sorted out, `compare()` function would work only for hard coded indices. How should I go about it, if I would like to sort it based on different indices. Is there a method that I can mention to do so?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

//void check_function(std::vector <std::vector <int> > *dataset)
//{
//    std::cout<<(*dataset)[0].size()<<std::endl;
//}

bool compare(const std::vector <std::vector <int> > &a, const std::vector <std::vector <int> > &b)
{
    return a[1] < b[1];
}

/* This works, but this sorts based on the first parameter of the vector rather than what I mention.
bool compare(const std::vector <int> &a, const std::vector <int> &b)
{
    return a < b;
}
*/    
int main()
{
    std::vector <int> data;
    std::vector <int> data2;
    std::vector <std::vector <int> > dataset;

    data.push_back(5);
    data.push_back(10);
    dataset.push_back(data);

    data2.push_back(5);
    data2.push_back(20);
    dataset.push_back(data2);

//    check_function(&dataset);
    std::sort(dataset.begin(), dataset.end(), compare);
    std::cout<< dataset[0][0]<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The issue is with the compare, not std::sort. You would need to create a compare that compares two instances of std::vector<int> .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting a container, you need a function that compare couples of element contained in the container.

So, sorting a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, you need a function that receive a couples of `std::vector<int>`.

But your `compare()` receive a couple of `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

That is wrong.

Off Topic: your `compare()` function (IMHO) is very dangerous because access to the second element of both vector without checking if they contain at least two elements.

I think you should, at least, use `at()` instead `operator[]`; just to perform a bound cecking and, in case, obtain a catchable exception; something like

```
bool compare(const std::vector <int> & a, const std::vector <int> & b)
{
    return a.at(1) < b.at(1);
}
```

**--- EDIT ---**

The OP ask

> how do I sort it based on an index that is decided in runtime?

Decided how? And where?

Suppose that is decided outside `compare()` (in the function that call `std::sort()`, by example), you can use a lambda function.

An example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
 {
   std::vector <std::vector <int> > dataset;

   dataset.emplace_back(std::initializer_list<int>{200, 1});
   dataset.emplace_back(std::initializer_list<int>{5, 56});

   auto val = 1U;

   std::sort(dataset.begin(), dataset.end(),
             [val](const std::vector <int> &a, const std::vector <int> &b)
              { return  a.at(val) < b.at(val); });

   std::cout << dataset[0][0] << ", " << dataset[0][1] << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: std::sort will pass references to two elements of dataset to the compare function, each of these elements will be a std::vector<int> .

Comment: [Please check the code here](https://gist.github.com/lharikrishnan1993/fae76536a9a55487c2e6774ac73e955b). Thanks. That works, but, how do I sort it based on an index that is decided during runtime, rather than hard coding it as 1?

Comment: @rcgldr - exactly; in the original code, `compare()` receive a couple of `std::vector<std::vector<int>> const &`; that is wrong.

Comment: @Harikrishnan - answer improved; hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Need to learn lambda expressions to understand the logic completely.

Comment: @Harikrishnan - yes: give a look at lambda functions; they are really usefull.